# How to enable chrome crash dump collection during automated testing?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, crash-reports

I know how to enable chrome's crash reporting interactively:

> Menu > Settings > Show advanced settings > Tick "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google"

However, I'm using chrome in an automated testing setup where we set a new `--user-data-dir` for each run (so there are no persisted settings, we just get the defaults).  Chrome is crashing occasionally (running our javascript/html application) and I would like to be able to report these crashes.

I thought I could add `--enable-crash-reporter` (according to the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)), but that doesn't seem to do anything.  (We already pass `--enable-logging` and a couple other flags on the command line.)

I have a test that triggered an "Aw, Snap":
[image]

But if I download the user-data-dir for that run and and point chrome at it, and then visit `chrome://crashes`, it says crash dumps are not enabled.
(The `chrome_debug.log` does not say anything about the Aw-Snap either.)

[image]

We're running chrome under Xvfb on Debian.  We're driving chrome via the direct webdriver (from Protractor).

Comment: Ever figure something out?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the "crashpad with content shell" docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/testing/using_crashpad_with_content_shell.md), the steps for using crashpad with content shell (a stripped down version of Chrome):

1. Create some directory for your crash dumps to go to (the docs suggest `tmp/crashes` on Linux and Mac, `%TEMP%\crashes` on Windows, and `/data/local/tmp/crashes` on Android)
2. Start Chrome with `--enable-crash-reporter --crash-dumps-dir=<your_dump_dir>` (looks like you got half of this)

So I'd try adding the `--crash-dumps-dir` flag.